# Any Good Reference for Kazdan-Warner Type Equations

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, elliptic-pde

The Kazdan-Warner Type equations I am talking about is the following:

Suppose X be a compact Riemannian manifold(of any dimension) and $A$, $B$, and $w$ to be smooth function, I hope to know more about the known result to the following equation:
$$\Delta u+ Ae^u-Be^{-u}-w=0 $$

Here is my questions:

1. Under some assumptions of A, B and w, is there any good reference for the solvability and uniqueness of this equation?
2. What is the obstruction for the existence of solution to this equation?

Comment: May [this] books help you "application of harmonic analysis in quantum statistical mechanics and quantum field theory 

[this]:https://books.google.dz/books?id=zQwTYTLlTRcC&pg=PA319&lpg=PA319&dq=Kazan-Warner+Type+Equations&source=bl&ots=YYNg0lRjba&sig=TdUQKaWNVRaZoDG23Io3WSGXlcw&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Kazan-Warner%20Type%20Equations&f=false

Comment: You should look to the Brezis-Merle paper http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03605309108820797?journalCode=lpde20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what counts as a good reference, but a statement on the solvability of the equation you mention is contained in the paper by Bryant-Wentworth (Lemma 3.4) http://www.math.ubc.ca/~jbryan/papers/kahlermonos.pdf